# Is there a CMD command to refresh the "Date modified" in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm workin on a batch script that automatically copies all log files with a max age (n) to a new location.

While testing the script i noticed, that there some log files were missing and the reason was, that the `Date modified` shown in the windows exporer does not refresh automatically. At the moment i only managed to update/refresh it by opening the log file.

The strange thing about is, that it shows me

> Date modified=16.05.2019 08:22

but when i open the file i see, that the last row was written 3 days later.
Is there any cmd command to refresh it automatically so my script will detect the file?

```
Robocopy %work_path% %file_path% /MaxAge:1 /S /XF *.exe /XF *.ini /XF *.dll /XF *.fdb /XD %~dp0
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Last modification date of a file is the date the file content was modified the last time. So either your PC time runs wrong by 72 hours, or you looked on wrong file on checking date, or the application writing the log file has it permanently open for writing while you copy the log file in which case the latest changes are perhaps not flushed to storage media by the application until accessing the file for reading operation by anther application. File read/write operations are usually done via file data buffers.

Comment: I just checked the source-code with out development and the problem is caused by our services that keep the file open. Thank You for the fast help.